# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.2/$injector/

Tags: c#, angular, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Help plaese
I have a little project which developed on ASP dotnet MVC with angular, when i uploading the build on windows IIS, angular is not loading the angular files,

Page look like this

[Page look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCopW.png)

code error is

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.2/$injector/modulerr?p0=myAppReg&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.8.2%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3Dn%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Fdev02%3A8080%2Fbundles%2Fangular%3Fv%3DWBZx8wk_-vJDZ3YonKXb00zJMs-JA9giQ01orZGP8zE1%3A10%3A168%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Fdev02%3A8080%2Fbundles%2Fangular%3Fv%3DWBZx8wk_-vJDZ3YonKXb00zJMs-JA9giQ01orZGP8zE1%3A49%3A468%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(http%3A%2F%2Fdev02%3A8080%2Fbundles%2Fangular%3Fv%3DWBZx8wk_-vJDZ3YonKXb00zJMs-JA9giQ01orZGP8zE1%3A47%3A197)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20e%20(http%3A%2F%2Fdev02%3A8080%2Fbundles%2Fangular%3Fv%3DWBZx8wk_-vJDZ3YonKXb00zJMs-JA9giQ01orZGP8zE1%3A47%3A438)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.invoke%20(http%3A%2F%2Fdev02%3A8080%2Fbundles%2Fangular%3Fv%3DWBZx8wk_-vJDZ3YonKXb00zJMs-JA9giQ01orZGP8zE1%3A48%3A16)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(http%3A%2F%2Fdev02%3A8080%2Fbundles%2Fangular%3Fv%3DWBZx8wk_-vJDZ3YonKXb00zJMs-JA9giQ01orZGP8zE1%3A46%3A148)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Fdev02%3A8080%2Fbundles%2Fangular%3Fv%3DWBZx8wk_-vJDZ3YonKXb00zJMs-JA9giQ01orZGP8zE1%3A46%3A287%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(http%3A%2F%2Fdev02%3A8080%2Fbundles%2Fangular%3Fv%3DWBZx8wk_-vJDZ3YonKXb00zJMs-JA9giQ01orZGP8zE1%3A11%3A76)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http%3A%2F%2Fdev02%3A8080%2Fbundles%2Fangular%3Fv%3DWBZx8wk_-vJDZ3YonKXb00zJMs-JA9giQ01orZGP8zE1%3A46%3A49)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20fb%20(http%3A%2F%2Fdev02%3A8080%2Fbundles%2Fangular%3Fv%3DWBZx8wk_-vJDZ3YonKXb00zJMs-JA9giQ01orZGP8zE1%3A50%3A153)